# What is the average time wanderers need to find something good?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have had wanderers out in the wasteland for about 7 hours and they came back with the average stuff like BB guns and rusty pistols. I load them with good armor and decent guns most are the highest level dwellers I have. Any suggestions? Also, can wanderers find dwellers and bring them back?

Comment: Is this a mod of some sort? The items you are discussing are not in Minecraft: Pocket Edition by default

Comment: I didn't put minecraft I don't know what it did.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of time to start finding decent stuff in the wasteland depends on the level of the dweller, the SPECIAL stats of the dweller, the weapon the dweller has and how many StimPacks/RadAways they have. The level of the dweller and their SPECIAL stats are especially important. With decent amounts of all of these, it may take 8-14 hours for decent equipment.